# Firefox, 2 clicks generated for a double click

Tags: html

In my page I have a button with onClick event,

```
<input type="button" onClick="openProductDetails();" value="Show product Info" />
```

on Firefox, when I double click the button, I get a design problem.

It's like I executed twice the onClick event.
[image]

This problem doesn't occur on IE.

I didn't find how to stop firing the double click on Firefox.

Comment: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: It's a well-known behavior, some browsers delay double click event until they're sure it's a double click (and not just a single one), others don't. Also this time is system and user specific. In general you should avoid, if possible, to handle both. If you can't then you have to add your own logic (postpone click event for, let's say, 300 ms and cancel it if another click occurs).

Answer (score -1):

You haven't provided any code examples? How can we possibly help without seeing how you've written your function. Debugging in the blind!

Try adding to the on click event a preventDefault function.
Assuming you're using jquery??

```
$("#button").on('click', function(e)) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Do something
}
```

If not this is the vanilla solution.

```
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault();
    // Do something
});
```